# How to get max of consecutive record entry in sql query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I know how to use `MAX()` function and `GROUP BY` clause in sql query but, in my case the records i want to group is bit different.

for example I have a following table

```
HostName   ModifyDate                Sr No
-------------------------------------------
PC-1       2015-12-04 08:45:52.847   1
PC-1       2015-12-04 08:48:51.025   2
PC-2       2015-12-04 08:50:01.125   3
PC-2       2015-12-04 08:50:45.545   4
PC-2       2015-12-04 08:53:44.897   5
PC-1       2015-12-04 09:02:17.524   6
PC-2       2015-12-04 09:18:36.788   7
PC-2       2015-12-04 09:22:01.041   8
PC-1       2015-12-04 09:31:41.744   9
```

And the result should be like this

```
HostName   ModifyDate                Sr No
------------------------------------------
PC-1       2015-12-04 08:48:51.025   2
PC-2       2015-12-04 08:53:44.897   5
PC-1       2015-12-04 09:02:17.524   6
PC-2       2015-12-04 09:22:01.041   8
PC-1       2015-12-04 09:31:41.744   9
```

[**Sql Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/994ea/1)

The above result shows the record of max date of consecutive HostName records. You can see there are 3 entries (SrNo 3,4,5) but I have taken only 5th which is latest from all of three. the same scenario also used in first two records (SrNo 1,2) I have taken only 2nd record which is latest from those two.

The problem is that I cannot take the Max Date Record. if I use `MAX(ModifyDate)` with group by `HostName` then it will return only two records (Sr No 8 and 9) which is latest. I want to take max record of each consecutive `HostName` entry.

**NOTE: I cannot create stored procedure for it. I want to get that record by single sql statement. And there is no Sr No field in the table. I have taken it just to understand the case.**

Comment: This is a classic gaps and islands problem. You'll find many solutions out there.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [Grouping Islands of Contiguous Dates](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/71550/) problem which can be solved using `ROW_NUMBER`:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/994ea/2/0)

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        grp     = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ModifyDate) -
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY HostName ORDER BY ModifyDate),
        SrNo    = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ModifyDate)
    FROM LOG
),
CteFinal AS(
    SELECT *,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY HostName, grp ORDER BY SrNo DESC)
    FROM Cte
)
SELECT
    HostName, ModifyDate, SrNo
FROM CteFinal
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY SrNo
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach..

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0fdbcc/1)

```
WITH CTE1 AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT ModifyDate)) RN,* FROM DATES9
),
CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT CAST(1 AS INT) AS NRN, * FROM CTE1 WHERE RN=1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST((CASE WHEN C1.HOSTNAME = C2.HOSTNAME THEN NRN ELSE NRN+1 END) AS INT) AS NRN,C1.*
    FROM CTE1 C1 INNER JOIN CTE2 C2 ON C2.RN = C1.RN-1
)
select  MAX(MODIFYDATE),HOSTNAME 
from CTE2
GROUP BY NRN,HOSTNAME
ORDER BY NRN
```